# Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinTarget'. when adding realm dependency in android studio

Tags: mongodb, android-studio, realm

Whenever i try to sync the module level gradle file with the dependency of mongodb realm

`id("io.realm.kotlin")`

i get the error which says

```
Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinTarget'.
```

```
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

The gradle jdk i am using is JBR version17.0.8

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("io.realm.kotlin")

}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mongodbtestkotlin"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.mongodbtestkotlin"
        minSdk = 29
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
    implementation ("io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.11.0")
    implementation ("io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.11.0")// If using Device Sync
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.0")

}
```

Comment: It appears this `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'` is missing from plugins. Also, did you add `id 'io.realm.kotlin' version '1.11.0' apply false` to the project level plug ins?